# 405 Method Not Allowed The method GET is not allowed for this resource (AppEngine, Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

NOTE: I think I have found what's wrong in my code, I had not installed the request module. I'm investigating this now.

I'm banging my head against the wall with this appengine application. Tried the remedies given for similar questions to no avail. Maybe someone can spot what the issue is?

Here's what I'm doing:

1) I create a product in the app based on the user's input. Once written to the ndb I call a page to display the recently created product:

```
import requests
....
r = requests.post('products_display', data = {'find_id_txt':prod_id_txt})
```

The request is routed through:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/products_add', AddProduct),      
    ('/products_display', DisplayProduct),    
    ...
], config = session_params, debug = True)
```

It then arrives at the correct handler and I get the 405 error (405 Method Not Allowed The method GET is not allowed for this resource). The browser shows this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/products_display
```

This is the code of the handler (for the moment I just display a page to tell if the product was found or not).

```
class DisplayProduct(BaseHandler):
    # Finds a product on exact Prod_ID property
    def get(self):
        user = usermgmt.get_user(self)
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        access = usermgmt.get_auth("Products")  
        client_name = usermgmt.get_client_subdomain()
        search_key = self.request.get('find_id_txt')
        find_query = models.Product.query(models.Product.prod_id == search_key, ancestor = get_products_key()).get()
        # Check if query returned a value
        if find_query:      
            template_values = {
                'client_name': client_name,              
                'user': user,
                'logout_url': logout_url,
                'alert_message': "Product1: " + search_key + " was found."
            }
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('alert-blue.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))               
        else:
            template_values = {
                'client_name': client_name,              
                'user': user,
                'logout_url': logout_url,
                'alert_message': "Product1: " + search_key + " could not be found."
            }
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('alert-yellow.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

I tried all possible combinations of sending a get, then a post request and changing get for post on the handler. Each time I logged out of the browser or use another one and still I get the error.

Here's the content of my app.yaml file:

```
#application: fpp-system
#version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /categories.*
  script: categories.application
  login: required

- url: /calendar.*
  script: calendars.application
  login: required

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /products.*
  script: products.application
  login: required

- url: /signin.*
  script: signin.application

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /test.*
  script: test.application

- url: /units.*
  script: units.application
  login: required 

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

The code is written using pydev on eclipse neon on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Once it's debugged I can upload it to Google's cloud.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

ADDED AFTER 1ST COMMENTS:

a) Copied indentation correctly: def get(self) and following are now indented correctly.

b) Added contents of app.yaml

c) The get function works well when I call it from an html page to find a product, here's the code snippet with the form to ask for required info:

```
 <form action="/products_display" method="post">
   <div><input value="" name="find_id_txt" size="15"></div>
   <div><input type="submit" value="Find"></div>
 </form><br>
```

but it gives the 405 error when I call it programmatically with:

```
r = requests.post('products_display', data = {'find_id_txt':prod_id_txt})
```

Comment: We need to see your `app.yaml` file.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation in the code? If so `def get()` needs to be further indented vs `class DisplayProduct()`

Comment: show your class BaseHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to troubleshoot:

```
import logging

class DisplayProduct(BaseHandler):
    def get:
        logging.info("this is a GET")

    def post:
        logging.info("this is a POST")
```

Then, send your current POST.  Next, send a request to: `http://localhost:8080/products_display?find_id_txt=test`.  Hopefully, you'll see what is happening.

Comment: Hi GAEfan: I tried the logging you suggested and couldn't get it to work. However you gave me an idea: instead of programmatically generating a POST request I create a GET request like: url_str = '/products_display?find_id_txt=' + prod_id_txt and then  self.redirect(url_str). I have two methods in display_product a post and a get. It now works.  This allowed me to find out that I had not installed the requests module. I'm looking into that now, but at least the app works.

Comment: Yes, this was the next step in troubleshooting.

Comment: Installing the requests module hits against other packages being needed: chardet, idfa etc. What would be the simplest way to send a post to the page displaying the newly stored product? As mentioned, I can do the trick with get, but I also call the same product display page from a find_product form elsewhere and the form submit button sends a post. As much as possible I would like to avoid code duplication by having identical get and get functions in the same handler.